# Google apps script - Why isn't my for-loop executing?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a simple script to clear the values from a specific Google Sheets range [H29:H] if the background color of the cell = #ffff00. While the script doesn't return any errors, it isn't making any changes to cells that meet those criteria (or anywhere else in the sheet). Any guidance as to where I am going wrong?

```
    function resetCells() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Test Sheet');
    var rangeData = sheet.getDataRange();
    var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();
    var searchRange = sheet.getRange('H29:H');
    var rangeColors = searchRange.getBackgrounds();

        for ( i = 29 ; i < lastRow - 1; i++){
          if(rangeColors[i][8] === '#ffff00'){
            sheet.getRange(i,8).clearContent();
          }; 
        };

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw your script, I thought that the index of `rangeColors` might not be corresponding to `i` in the for a loop. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue. In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```
for ( i = 29 ; i < lastRow - 1; i++){
  if(rangeColors[i][8] === '#ffff00'){
    sheet.getRange(i,8).clearContent();
  }; 
};
```

##### To:

```
for (i = 0; i < rangeColors.length; i++) {
  if (rangeColors[i][0] === '#ffff00') {
    sheet.getRange(i + 29, 8).clearContent();
  }
}
```

or, in your situation, when `sheet.getRange(i + 29, 8).clearContent()` is used at outside of the loop, the process cost might be able to be reduced a little. In this case, please modify as follows.

```
var rangeList = rangeColors.reduce((ar, [h], i) => {
  if (h === '#ffff00') ar.push("H" + (i + 29));
  return ar;
}, []);
sheet.getRangeList(rangeList).clearContent();
```

- In this modification, when the background color of the cell of column "H" is `#ffff00`, the cell content is clear.

#### Reference:

- [Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list)

Answer (score 0):

**What you did wrong**

In `rangeColors[i][8]` you were assuming `rangeColors` related to the cells in the spreadsheet. But they actually relate to the `searchRange` you made. So `rangeColors[i][8]`should be `rangeColors[i][0]`. Where `i` starts at `0`.

To make it "extra fun" for you `rangeColors` is an array which is zero-based indexed. And when you are working with a range you can retreive the first cell with `range.getCell(1, 1)`, not `range.getCell(0, 0)`.

**Because I got a little carried away I wrote this solution ( may be an interesting extra to read )**

I don't think mapping an array of arrays (`rangeColors`) to a range is a great way to do this; It's hard to keep track on what your code is doing.

What I did was:

1. Create a range to check
2. Generate column and row numbers for all the cells in the range. Note that these are relative to the range, not the stylesheet. So `range.getCell(1, 1)` is the top left cell **in the range**. This is the (main) mistake you made in your code.
3. Do whatever you want with every individual cell in the range.

**code:**

```
resetCells( '#ffff00' );

function resetCells( color ) {
  const app= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = app.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const range = sheet.getRange('F4:F50');

  for( let row = 1; row < range.getNumRows() + 1; row++ ) {
    for( let column = 1; column < range.getNumColumns() + 1; column++ ) {

      const cell = range.getCell( row, column );
      if( cell.getBackground() === color )
        cell.clearContent();
        
    }
  }

}
```

*Disclaimer: I never used this google-app-script before. So I may have done something wrong performance-wise; iterating a large amount of cells takes a little long;*